# Drop Table in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is it possible to execute a SQL command to drop a table directly within PyDev?  I have been going to the terminal and opening dbshell but wanted to see if there is a way to do this directly in PyDev.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

see [pydev interactive console](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html), when on Console view, click the arrow to open "PyDev Console", however consider a better choice like adding [SQL Explorer plugin](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/) to your Eclipse ide